# Dict with two quotes

Tags: python, dictionary

I Want To Store A Dict `{'key':'value}` Then Add It To Some Other Strings

`x = {'key', 'value'}` And `intro = 'The Dict Is'`

And When I Get Them Together It'll Be Like This `All = intro + str(x)`

Then `All` Will Be Like This `The Dict Is  {'key', 'value'}`

I Know All This. But What I Want To Know Is, How To Make `All` Look Like This `The Dict Is  {"key", value"}` With Two quotes Without Using `intro + str(x).replace("'", '"')`.

Comment: This whole thing is stored in a string, right? ```The Dict Is  {'key', 'value'}```

Comment: Yes `type(All)=string`

Comment: why u wanna double cot ?

Comment: I want to use it in html or url query string variable if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You may use `json` module to handle json files better.

```py
import json

my_dict = json.dumps({'key':'value'})
intro = 'The Dict Is'

All = intro + str(my_dict).replace(':',',')
print(All)
```

Output: `The Dict Is{"key", "value"}`

Comment: If i was going to use `replace()` wouldn't it be better if i used `replace("'", '"')` ?

Comment: Acc. to your question, Yes, both give the same answer and any method is fine.